# How Can I use postgresql DEFAULT keyword in a prepared statement in GO?

Tags: postgresql, go

Consider that I have a table t1: col1: `varchar(255)`, col2: `boolean DEFAULT true`

and I created this prepared statement p1: `INSERT INTO t1(col1,col2) VALUES ($1,$2)`

and in GO I am executing my prepared statement but based on condition1 I want to pass the `DEFAULT` keyword to the second parameter in the prepared statement i.e

```
if condition1 {
   sql.Exec(p1,"FOO","DEFAULT")  // but this returns an error:  invalid input syntax for type boolean: "DEFAULT"
} else{
  //pass other parameters to the prepared statement
}
```

summary: I am trying to end with this sql statement:

```
INSERT INTO t1(col1,col2) VALUES ('FOO',DEFAULT)
```

but I am getting this:

```
INSERT INTO t1(col1,col2) VALUES ('FOO','DEFAULT')   //quotations on DEFAULT
```

anybody knows how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better, since you already have an if/else detecting the situation where you don't have a value to pass, to instead do

```
INSERT INTO t1 (col1) VALUES ('FOO');
```

and let postgres use the default value for the other column.

Comment: if you pass null to column, null is inserted, not default: `t=# create table dfnn(i int default 0);
CREATE TABLE
t=# insert into dfnn select null;
INSERT 0 1
t=# select * from dfnn;
 i
---

(1 row)`