# How to use DEFAULT when inserting rows into postgres sql database

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, go, default

Consider that I have a table t1 in my postgres database like so:

```sql
CREATE TABLE t1 (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
    col_2 TEXT DEFAULT "foo", 
    col_3 TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT "bar", 
    ...
    col_X INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 42
);
```

And that I receive a JSON object `obj` which I unmarshall in a struct `ObjStrct`:

```golang
type ObjStrct {
    id *int32  `json:id,omitempty`, 
    s1 *string `json:s1,omitempty`, 
    s2 *string `json:s2,omitempty`, 
    ...
    nr *int32  `json:nr,omitempty`
}
var obj ObjStrct
err := json.NewDecoder(request.Body).Decode(&obj)
// error handling has been done
```

Now I want to insert that object into my database:

```golang
// connection to db established
row := db.QueryRow(
        `INSERT INTO 
            t1 (col_1, col_2, ..., col_X)
        VALUES
            ($1, $2, ..., $X)
        RETURNING 
            id;`, 
        *obj.s1, *obj.s2, ..., *obj.nr)
```

The issue is: All those `obj.*`-values could be `nil` in which case the sql DEFAULT value should be used.

My question is: How do I achieve this?

- datatypes from the sql package (sql.Null<TYPE>) do not support the DEFAULT keyword afaik.
- Functions like `func defaultOnNil(v *int32) any { ... }` returning "DEFAULT" when `v` is nil and `v` instead do not work. See [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40866712/how-can-i-use-postgresql-default-keyword-in-a-prepared-statement-in-go)

Answer (score 2):

To use the `DEFAULT` value of a column an `INSERT` should **exclude the column** while inserting.

This means, you'll need to process the JSON object, find out which values are nil, and remove them from the query.

For example, if the JSON object has `s2` as nil, then `col2` should be removed from your query; it should be modified as:

```
row := db.QueryRow(
        `INSERT INTO 
            t1 (col_1, ..., col_X) -- "col2" removed here
        VALUES
            ($1, ..., $X)          -- "$2" removed here
        RETURNING 
            id, col2;`,            -- "col2" added here
        *obj.s1, *obj.s2)
```

This is easily done by any ORM that implements Dynamic SQL functionality.

Comment: Well I guess there is a new topic for me study :D

Comment: I was rather looking for something the sql package does with "NULL" and the NULL-datatypes. That it replaces the placeholder in the query with "NULL" when the value is "nil". I would have loved to see something similar with "DEFAULT". But this solution looks very promising too, thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is send the keyword DEFAULT instead of the value parsed from the json. So:

```
row := db.QueryRow(
        `INSERT INTO 
            t1 (col_1, col_2, ..., col_X)
        VALUES
            ($1, $2, ..., $X)
        RETURNING 
            id;`, 
        *obj.s1, DEFAULT, ..., *obj.nr);
```

You do not use quotes around DEFAULT, in this usage it is a keyword.

Comment: If I'd know that I'd always use the default value for a specific column i could do it like so. But I don't. And I haven't figured out a way how I could write a function which returns just DEFAULT when the provided value is "nil"

Comment: I'm not sure if the `DEFAULT`keyword should be included in the SQL statement or as a method parameter (as in your example).